# Perforce can I bulk modify other workspaces?

Tags: perforce

We have 30 User's and 26 of them are Artists, and all of their workspaces were created manually with their username and a project alias. Now we want to add some new view's to the user's workspace, is there a way to do a bulk-edit on that with a perforce command?

Can I, as an admin modify a workspaces view and that would be reflected, next time the Artist opens up perforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce's built-in solution for this is called **streams**.

With a "stream-based" workflow, each project (and each codeline for each project, if applicable) is defined by a "stream" specification that defines which paths the project contains, and its relation to other streams, if any.

When a workspace is associated with a stream, the view is automatically generated based on the stream specification, and modifications to the stream specification are automatically propagated to all workspaces associated with that stream.

---

With a "classic" client specification, each workspace has its own independently created view, which is not tied to any other workspace or any other object.  As an admin you can modify an other user's client spec via the `p4 client -f` command, and you could potentially script this command to automate that modification across multiple client specs.

However, I'd recommend looking at streams as an easier solution; it might be a bit of work up front to migrate from manual views to stream views, but if you anticipate the need to make changes like this frequently, using streams will be quite a bit easier than maintaining your own tooling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information and as well going over the classic approach!